# imfinfo function in matlab for grayscale

Tags: matlab

I want to ask about matlab "imfinfo" function, this funtion will return some information about my figure.
 I used it on RGB figure and it's worked, but when i am using it with grayscale figure it return only some array.

Here is the code :

```
dolphin = imread('lumba2.jpg');
info = imfinfo('lumba2.jpg');
display(info)
```

it will work and return info about the image.

But, when i am using it on grayscale it won't return the info

```
dolphin = imread('lumba2.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(dolphin)
imshow(I)
info = imfinfo('lumba2.jpg');
display(info)
```

it's return the array of grayscale image,

my question is can we get figure information for the grayscale
or it's just for the RGB only?

Comment: `imfinfo` gives you image **file** info. In other words, it's looking at the file `lumba2.jpg`, **not** whatever figure you happen to be displaying. As far as I can see, both calls to `imfinfo` should return the exact same data, unless you've modified the image file somehow.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the grayscale conversion of the RGB image. Put a semicolon `;` at the end of the call to `rgb2gray`.

Comment: Ah i get it now, rgb2array will return the conversion and imfinfo read from a file not a figure